# Failed to read converted .ods from soffice command

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, java

I have converted **.xls** file to **.ods** by using below command in terminal

```
COMMAND : soffice --headless --convert-to ods abcd.xls
```

After conversion I am not able to read **fileName.ods** using **SpreadSheet API** of **jOpenDocument1.3.jar**. When ever I try to read .ods file it will throw **NullPointer Exception** .

I am working in Ubuntu platform, if I convert **.xls** file to **.ods** using **LibreOffice** then it is working fine but if I convert it using **soffice** terminal then it is throwing exception!.

Is there any way to convert file(s) using command line, so that Java code able to read it properly.

I am using below code to read converted **fileName.ods** file .

```
File file = new File(path);
String sheetName = "SheetName"; // spread Sheet Name
Sheet sheet = SpreadSheet.createFromFile(file).getSheet(sheetName);
```

"**createFromFile**" is giving NullPointer Exception

```
ava.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jopendocument.dom.ODPackage.getODDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.jopendocument.dom.ODPackage.getSpreadSheet(Unknown Source)
    at org.jopendocument.dom.spreadsheet.SpreadSheet.createFromFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.thales.dbtool.controller.DBManageController.getUiParamsFromExcel(DBManageController.java:1316)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Generally I would consider this a bug or something in the XLS the conversion tool does not support. I would have asked this on their forum: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/questions/

Comment: Do you have this also when you use the libreoffice --headless command?

Comment: @Bruni : We are facing the same issue there is no difference between soffice and libreoffice .  After  conversion the file size is more then the actual file . Is there any other way to convert .xls to .ods .